# Why do My C Code go Wrong

Tags: c, pointers

The below is my code. Compiler generates the errors as

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Shelf{
    int clothes;
    int *books;
};
struct Shelf b;
b.clothes=5;
*(b.books)=6;
```

Compiler generates the errors as below for both statements `b.clothes=5;` and `b->books=6;` in above code.

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘->’ token
```

I'm not a beginner at C and I believe that what I have written is correct. Kindly solve my problem

Comment: `b` is not a pointer, so `->` notation is just wrong. If you are not a beginner as you say, you should not be believing it is correct.

Comment: I have seen it work some where else. Atleast @EugeneSh. why should my statement `b.clothes=5` should go wrong with that error

Comment: Assignments (to be distinguished from initialisations) in global scope aren't valid C (in most cases ;-)).

Comment: Because of the scope as stated in the answers below. And no, it can't work elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**FIRST**

You cannot do this

```
struct Shelf{
    int clothes;
    int books;
};
struct Shelf b;
b.clothes=5;
b.books=6;
```

In global scope

You can assign value inside a function

```
int main (void )
{
   b.clothes=5;
   b.books=6;
}
```

Or initializing values on declaration

```
struct Shelf b = { .clothes = 5, .books = 6 };
```

Moreover as you can see `b` is not a pointer so using `->` is not correct: use `.` to access members of struct.

---

**SECOND**

Your struct has a pointer member `book`

```
struct Shelf{
    int clothes;
    int *books;
};
```

What you can do is to set it to the address of another variable, like

```
int book = 6;
struct Shelf b = { .clothes = 5, .books = &book };
```

Or allocate memory for that pointer like

```
int main (void )
{
   b.clothes=5;
   b.books=malloc(sizeof(int));
   if (b.books != NULL)
   {
       *(b.books) = 6;
   }
}
```

BTW I guess you want an array of books, so

```
int main (void )
{
   b.clothes=5;
   b.books=malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX_N_OF_BOOKS);
   if (b.books != NULL)
   {
       for (int i=0; i<MAX_N_OF_BOOKS; i++)
          b.books[i] = 6;
   }
}
```

---

**COMPETE TEST CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Shelf
{
    int clothes;
    int *books;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Shelf b;

    b.clothes = 5;
    b.books = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (b.books != NULL)
    {
        *(b.books) = 6;
    }

    printf ("clothes: %d\n", b.clothes);
    printf ("book: %d\n", *(b.books) );
}
```

OUTPUT

```
clothes: 5
book: 6
```

Comment: You can do `struct Shelf *b=malloc(sizeof(struct Shelf));`

Comment: Hii @LPs I tried working with `*(b.books)` as mentioned by you and now it has the error ` error: expected ‘)’ before ‘.’ token`

Comment: @NaseerMohammad I really don't know. You should post your code. Take a look at the example code I added, or take a look at it on [ideone.it](http://ideone.com/h4o9Qw)

Comment: Hi @LPs i I realized that this error is because we are initializing structure variables in global scope. Thanks for that. It would be of great help if you could tell me why do C program doesnt allow do this?

Comment: @NaseerMohammad because of you simply can't put code outside a function. You can, as shown in my answer, initialize the whole variable within declaration.

Answer (score 2):

`b` is a struct, **not a pointer**, so `->` is not correct.

It's like doing `(*b).books`, which is wrong.

```
struct Shelf{
    int clothes;
    int *books;
};
```

One data member of the struct is a pointer, however:

```
struct Shelf b;
```

is not a pointer, it is just a struct as I said before.

As for your question in comment:

```
b.clothes=5;
```

is correct. Also something like this would be ok:

```
int number = 6;
b.books = &number;
```

Answer (score 0):

`->` operator used to access of member of  struct via pointer.  `b` is not dynamically allocated so `b->books=6;` is wrong. You should first allocate memory for member `books` and then dereference it.

```
b.books = malloc(sizeof(int));
*(b.books)= 6;
```

Comment: `->` has nothing to do with dynamic allocations. it dereferences a pointer before accessing a struct member. In many classic C APIs, a `struct` is allocated automatically (local variable) and a pointer is passed to the function, this function of course will have to use the `->` operator.